# Problem trying to animate Brownian Motion with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im really new in programming with Python and in my final project I need to create this animation where 10 points are randomly moving in space (Brownian motion).

My teacher gave me some examples but I just cant figure out why my program is not working correctly. The error says:

> "_included_frames frame_dir=os.path.dirname(frame_list[0]),
>
> IndexError: list index out of range"

Sorry if I didn´t express myself correctly but also English is not my native language.

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

N=10
x=500*np.random.random(N)
y=500*np.random.random(N)
z=500*np.random.random(N)

def frame(w):
    ax.clear()


    x=x+np.random.normal(0.0,50.0,10)
    y=y+np.random.normal(0.0,50.0,10)
    z=z+np.random.normal(0.0,50.0,10)

    mensaje="Movimiento Browniano"
    plt.title(mensaje)
    ax.set_xlim3d(-500.0,500.0)
    ax.set_ylim3d(-500.0,500.0)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-500.0,500.0) 

    plot=ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c='r')


    return plot


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, frame, frames=100, blit=False)

anim.save( 'MovimientoBrowniano.html', fps=5 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main problems with your code.

1. `x`,`y` and `z` are attempted to be changed locally in your function. However you really want to change the variables defined outside of the function scope. You may easily do that by declaring them globally: Add `global x,y,z` in your function.
2. You are trying to save the animation to an html file. That is no valid video format. I don't know which format you are targeting here, but a common option would be an animated gif, which could be produced by

   ```
   anim.save('MovimientoBrowniano.gif', writer = "pillow", fps=5 )
   ```

Comment: Than you for your answer, I already solved the problem changing x,y,z for a,b,c in my frame función. But I'll try yours and see what happens :)